# jQuery Mobile Slider create event not firing

Tags: jquery-mobile

First time I am using [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) the slider create event seems to not want to fire.

According to [jQuery Slider page](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/) the following events should work (create/start/stop), I did get start/stop to work but not the create, code below:

```
  <script>
      $(function () {
          $("#slider-s").slider({
              create: function (event, ui) {
                  console.log("creating");
              },
              start: function (event, ui) {
                  console.log("start moving");
              },
              stop: function (event, ui) {
                  console.log("stop moving");
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
  <input type="range" name="slider-s" id="slider-s" value="25" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true">
```

So every time I move up the slider I get `start moving` and when I stop it I get `stop moving` but I thought I would get `creating` once the slider has been loaded/created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/6dQ9E/

The point is to use proper page event to detect right widget event. Also you should never used classic document ready with jQuery Mobile, sometimes it works just fine and sometimes it behaves extremely weird. That's why jQuery Mobile page events exist. Read more abut it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.

#### Javascript used:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on('slidecreate', '#slider-s', function(){ 
        console.log("create");
    });    
    $(document).on('slidestart', '#slider-s', function(){ 
        console.log("start");
    });
    $(document).on('slidestop', '#slider-s', function(){ 
        console.log("stop");
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you, only thing I wanted to do was a cross browser web app working on every device, because the touch event was not working very well in Phones I had to use jQuery Mobile, oh well, again thanks for your help.

Comment: np m8 I am glad to help

Comment: Just want to add `pagecreate` somehow duplicated my slider (I know weird) but `pageinit` worked as intended.